# Handlebars two products on template

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

So I have a simple template where I call my products very easily, the problem is that now I want to show two products per loop, but handlebars manage it as the same giving the two elements the same data.

This is the template:

```
      <script id="template_prod" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#productos}}
        <div class="itemproducto">
          <a class="productos producto1">
            <img src="{{thumb}}">
            <p>{{nombre}}</p>
          </a>
          <a class="productos producto2">
            <img src="{{thumb}}">
            <p>{{nombre}}</p>
          </a>
        </div>
       {{/productos}} 
      </script>
```

edit 2: JSON Data + Function

```
var source = $("#template_prod").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
var data = { 
  productos: [
    {
    "nombre":"foo","thumb":"bar"
    }, /*repeat ad infinitum*/
  ]
}; 
$("#listaproductos").append(template(data));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the data you are passing to render this template so we can see what the template has to work with and also the code for any relevant helpers.

Comment: Edited the question to add JSON Data.

Answer (score 0):

Use handlebars #each helper.

```
  {{#each productos}}
    <div class="itemproducto">
      <a class="productos producto1">
        <img src="{{thumb}}">
        <p>{{nombre}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this is not what im trying to do, i have two <a> elements (".producto1" and ".producto2") inside ".itemproducto" and i need to show two products from the JSON array in the same loop.

Comment: @user2770956 oh you can't do that, unless you change your data structure, you don't need to change the json, just add a computed property that combines the two properties in one, and loop over that.